# Is there any way to tell the compiler that an integer type need not be truncated?

Tags: c++, integer, short

take this code snippet

```
void thing(signed short ss);
void test(int i){
    thing((signed short)i);
}
```

both gcc and clang generate

```
        movswl  %di, %edi
        jmp     thing(int)
```

however I know that the argument is between -32768 and 32767. And I can't change any of the argument types. So that movswl is basically a nop. In fact, gcc does a truncation every time it recieves a short argument. So it actually truncates it twice per in some function calls.

ideally I'd want a sort of assert_within_bounds_cast function that's sort of a cross between reinterpret_cast and bit_cast that basically says "don't worry about truncating, just use whatever register size is most convenient". I tried building it myself using `__builtin_unreachable()` and `reinterpret_cast` but it didn't work consistently and sometimes made things worse.

Comment: Seems like a microoptimization.  Did you profile your code and find this particular instruction to be a bottleneck?  If not, it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Use `int` instead of `short` as much as possible, then the issue doesn’t arise.

Comment: Can you show what you built with `__builtin_unreachable`? I have had similar problem in the past that I was able to address with clang's `__builtin_assume(in bounds)` and GCC `if (outside bounds) __builtin_unreachable`

Comment: We need more context.  Why is the signature of `thing` declared as it is?

Comment: Why can't `thing()` be specified to accept an `int` argument?

Answer (score -1):

If you can't change the argument types to `test`, you're stuck - callers can't possibly know that your function expects `signed short` when it accepts an `int` (which *might* be wider, but not always), and callers of the function may pass it an `int` outside of your control

Is it possible you can overload the function?

```cpp
void thing(signed short ss);
void test(int i){
    // consider asserting here too
    thing((signed short)i);
}
void test(signed short i){
    thing(i);
}
```

Finally, watch out when analyzing the results of really trivial / non-representative cases - if you really have `void` functions without a mutable arg, they may be completely dropped when (further) optimizations are applied, so you can't easily have a case where both full optimizations run (which may discover and fix your case) *and* the function(s) exist at all!

Comment: The problem is gcc truncates all short arguments regardless of if it's already a short or not.